# Value is not getting fetched from database using mysqli bind_result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am trying to fetch the `int` that is found in my database table using mysqli. I then bind the result using `bind_result()`. However, when I try to use the value I simply get a 0.
How can I deal with this?

My code is looking like this:

```
$sql = <<<EOF
        SELECT
        project_salary_amount
        FROM projects_set_salary
        WHERE project_id = ? ORDER BY project_salary_id DESC LIMIT 1
EOF;
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql) or die ("Feil i database<br>" . $sql . "<br><b>Feilmelding:</b> " . $mysqli->error);
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $project_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($dbb_salary_amount);
    $db_salary_amount = $dbb_salary_amount;
    $num_salary_results = $stmt->num_rows;
    $stmt->free_result();
    $stmt->close();

    if($num_salary_results == 0){
        $sql = <<<EOF
        INSERT INTO
        projects_set_salary (project_id)
        VALUES ($project_id)
EOF;
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql) or die ("Feil i database<br>" . $sql . "<br><b>Feilmelding:</b> " . $mysqli->error);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
        $db_salary_amount = 10;
        $html_set_salary = "";
        $html_set_salary .= "<form id=\"form_send_salary\"method=\"post\" action=\"create_set_salary.php\">\n";
        $html_set_salary .= "<input type=\"number\" name=\"set_salary\" value=\"$db_salary_amount\">";
    }
    else{
        $html_set_salary = "";
        $html_set_salary .= "<form id=\"form_send_salary\"method=\"post\" action=\"create_set_salary.php\">\n";
        $html_set_salary .= "<input type=\"number\" name=\"set_salary\" value=\"$db_salary_amount\">";
    }
```

Now, it does not display 10 inside the input box. Which means it does not execute the if statement. However, why am I not getting any results from `$db_salary_amount`? I know I probably didn't have to change the variable from `$db_salary_amount` to `$db_salary_amount`. I was just trying to find out where the problem was.

Comment: I have never seen queries in EOF (heredoc) statements like that.

Comment: I took over the job by another programmer, he wrote it like that. So I decided to stick with his way of writing it to avoid seperate methods.

Comment: @Sean I have used both in other queries. Hasn't been the problem so far.

Comment: It looks like you never do a `$stmt->fetch();` after doing `$stmt->bind_result($dbb_salary_amount);`. from http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php -> `When mysqli_stmt_fetch() is called to fetch data, the MySQL client/server protocol places the data for the bound columns into the specified variables`

Comment: Oh, of course! That solved it :) Thank you. If you could please add the answer with a description of WHY a fetch is necessary that would be great for others :)

Comment: Also `VALUES ($project_id)` should be `VALUES (?)`. You should bind in all places.

Comment: @chris85 Like this `$stmt->bind_param("i", $project_id);`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a `->fetch()` after `bind_result()`

```
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($dbb_salary_amount);
$stmt->fetch(); // <--- missing this ->fetch()
$db_salary_amount = $dbb_salary_amount;
```

from the docs for [`->bind_result()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) -> `When mysqli_stmt_fetch() is called to fetch data, the MySQL client/server protocol places the data for the bound columns into the specified variables var1, ....`